# Zooming in using Mouse Wheel

Tags: vb.net, graph, charts, controls, zooming

So I have a graph, sometimes this graph goes up to 1000 in terms of the Y values and its far too hard to see individual points/axes interceptions.

This will allow me to click and drag an area to zoom in, however this ruins the X and Y values/intervals and also adds scrollbars to the graph which I do not want!

```
Chart1.ChartAreas(0).CursorX.IsUserSelectionEnabled = True
Chart1.ChartAreas(0).CursorY.IsUserSelectionEnabled = True
```

Is there a way to implement this using the mouse wheel and click to drag rather than using scrollbars?

Comment: can you confirm what charting control you're using?

Comment: I am using MS Chart Control, the one that comes standard with Visual Studio 2012

Comment: [This post][1] has working code and references the MSDN documentation.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18892201/how-do-you-use-the-zooming-ui-in-mschart-for-net

Comment: That isnt the problem, I can already click drag to zoom. That function can be implemented through two lines of code-seen in the original post. However, this method ruins my axes-in terms of the intervals and also adds ridiculously long scrollbars. I was wondering, if anyone had or knew how to code this into a scroll wheel event. Afterwards, I would try to implement a click and drag method to view the chart rather than scroll bars.  Thanks,

Comment: According to an old post from a forum you might be able to use the InkPicture control's InkPicture_Painted event to catch any mouse scrolling event which is part of the MS Tablet PC type lib  source https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/a-worksheet-onscroll-event-how-cool-is-that.287154/

Answer (score 1):

i found the answer in another question
[Enabling mouse wheel zooming in a Microsoft Chart Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16787050/enabling-mouse-wheel-zooming-in-a-microsoft-chart-control)

but it is in c# .. i converted it to vb.net

```
Private Sub growthChart_MouseEnter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles growthChart.MouseEnter
    growthChart.Focus()
End Sub


 Private Sub growthChart_MouseWheel(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles growthChart.MouseWheel
    Try
        With growthChart
            If (e.Delta < 0) Then
                .ChartAreas(0).AxisX.ScaleView.ZoomReset()
                .ChartAreas(0).AxisY.ScaleView.ZoomReset()
            End If

            If (e.Delta > 0) Then
                Dim xMin As Double = .ChartAreas(0).AxisX.ScaleView.ViewMinimum
                Dim xMax As Double = .ChartAreas(0).AxisX.ScaleView.ViewMaximum
                Dim yMin As Double = .ChartAreas(0).AxisY.ScaleView.ViewMinimum
                Dim yMax As Double = .ChartAreas(0).AxisY.ScaleView.ViewMaximum
                Dim posXStart As Double = (.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.PixelPositionToValue(e.Location.X) _
                            - ((xMax - xMin) _
                            / 4))
                Dim posXFinish As Double = (.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.PixelPositionToValue(e.Location.X) _
                            + ((xMax - xMin) _
                            / 4))
                Dim posYStart As Double = (.ChartAreas(0).AxisY.PixelPositionToValue(e.Location.Y) _
                            - ((yMax - yMin) _
                            / 4))
                Dim posYFinish As Double = (.ChartAreas(0).AxisY.PixelPositionToValue(e.Location.Y) _
                            + ((yMax - yMin) _
                            / 4))
                .ChartAreas(0).AxisX.ScaleView.Zoom(posXStart, posXFinish)
                .ChartAreas(0).AxisY.ScaleView.Zoom(posYStart, posYFinish)
            End If
        End With


    Catch ex As System.Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

It worked well in zooming in but in zooming out it needs adjusting.

Answer (score 0):

Found this code which improves on zoom in positioning with different scales.

I have further improved it and it now also zooms out effectively as well as zooms in.

https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?795865-RESOLVED-MSChart-Zoom-with-mouse-roller

```
Private Sub Chart1_MouseWheel(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Chart1.MouseWheel
    Try

        With Chart1

            Dim xMin As Double = Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.ScaleView.ViewMinimum
            Dim xMax As Double = Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.ScaleView.ViewMaximum ' + Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.ScaleView.Position
            Dim yMin As Double = Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisY.ScaleView.ViewMinimum
            Dim yMax As Double = Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisY.ScaleView.ViewMaximum ' + Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.ScaleView.Position

            Dim xValue As Double = Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.PixelPositionToValue(e.Location.X)
            Dim yValue As Double = Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisY.PixelPositionToValue(e.Location.Y)

            Dim posXFinish As Double
            Dim posXStart As Double

            Dim posYFinish As Double
            Dim posYStart As Double



            'this code checks to see if you are within a certain percentage of the starting point
            ' and if you are it will not zoom in

            If e.Delta > 0 Then
                'check zoom  for x Start
                If (xValue - (xValue - xMin) / scale) >= xValue Then
                    posXStart = xValue - (xValue - xMin)
                Else
                    posXStart = xValue - (xValue - xMin) / scale
                End If

                'check zoom  for x finish
                If xValue >= (posXStart + (xMax - xMin) / scale) Then
                    posXFinish = posXStart + (xMax - xMin)
                Else
                    posXFinish = posXStart + (xMax - xMin) / scale
                End If

                'check zoom for Y start
                If (yValue - (yValue - yMin) / scale) >= yValue Then
                    posYStart = yValue - (yValue - yMin)
                Else
                    posYStart = yValue - (yValue - yMin) / scale
                End If

                'check zoom for Y finish
                If yValue >= (posYStart + (yMax - yMin) / scale) Then
                    posYFinish = posYStart + (yMax - yMin)
                Else
                    posYFinish = posYStart + (yMax - yMin) / scale
                End If
            ElseIf e.Delta < 0 Then 
                'check zoom  for x Start
                If (xValue - (xValue - xMin) * scale) <= xValue Then
                    posXStart = xValue - (xValue - xMin)
                Else
                    posXStart = xValue - (xValue - xMin) * scale
                End If

                'check zoom  for x finish
                If xValue <= (posXStart + (xMax - xMin) * scale) Then
                    posXFinish = posXStart + (xMax - xMin)
                Else
                    posXFinish = posXStart + (xMax - xMin) * scale
                End If

                'check zoom for Y start
                If (yValue - (yValue - yMin) * scale) >= yValue Then
                    posYStart = yValue - (yValue - yMin)
                Else
                    posYStart = yValue - (yValue - yMin) * scale
                End If

                'check zoom for Y finish
                If yValue >= (posYStart + (yMax - yMin) * scale) Then
                    posYFinish = posYStart + (yMax - yMin)
                Else
                    posYFinish = posYStart + (yMax - yMin) * scale
                End If

            End If

            Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.ScaleView.Zoom(posXStart, posXFinish)
            Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisY.ScaleView.Zoom(posYStart, posYFinish)


        End With


    Catch ex As System.Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```